# Xcode not allows me to create local git

Tags: git, xcode4

So I'm trying to create a new project and I want to create a local Git repository for it. I'm using Xcode 4; I just downloaded and installed the latest version. When I go to make a new project and get to the point where I need to enter a name for my project the "Create local git repository" checkbox it is grayed out. I have already tried to create a symlink to where Xcode thinks Git should be with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing grayed out checkbox for “Create local git repository”]

Comment: I know this has already been answered and accepted, but doesn't the text "The folder "Docouments" contains a git repository" give the game away a bit?

Comment: The problem I had with this is that Xcode had cached the presence of a git repository, despite the fact that I'd deleted not only the .git, but also the directory containing it. Had to restart xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because there is already a git repository in disk folder (It's written in your screenshot). If it's created by mistake, remove it (`.git` folder in `.` or  `..`) and try again. Note that you don't need to provide your own git executable - Xcode4 has it.

Answer (score 2):

You just overwrite Xcode’s copy of git, which I can only assume is not a recommended thing to do. Reinstate it with this:

```
sudo ln -f /usr/libexec/git-core/git /usr/bin/git
```

And as mspasov said, it’s because there is already a git repository.